# How to limit keyboard input with phone number in a gridcolumn tag?

Tags: html, reactjs

I have a code line that input a phone number in the box.

`<GridColumn field="phoneNumber" title="Phone Number" editor="text"/>`

With the code below I can input all text from keyboard. But I want to limit keyboard input with number and text "-" only for this column, for example **123-456-7890**

I cannot use numberic for editor because it not allow to imput "-" keyboard.

I am using GridColumnProps from GridColumn component of Kendo React.

Anyone can help me get a solution?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of `react-number-format` npm package. Here's the link: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-number-format

> This will help you in adding some custom logic as per your requirement.

Comment: Thanks for your advise, but I do not want to use number format, I want user can input with free format(ex: 1-2-3-4567, 7543-6543234).

Answer (score 0):

You can use [input type="tel" and/or the pattern attribute](https://www.w3schools.com/Tags/att_input_type_tel.asp) for your input field.

Comment: But I must use Gridcolumn tag in here, I cannot use more input tag to apply type="tel" in it

Comment: then you should be able to just use the pattern attribute.

Comment: I tried again with your advise but I can input other text normally. It is seem no effect with GridColumn

Comment: Hmm, maybe you can put another element within your GridColumn and add the attributes there:
`<GridColumn><input type="tel" pattern="[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{3}"></input><GridColumn>`